# Change selector on the fly?

Tags: android

I have an image selector that has the "pressed" state set to a particular drawable.  I want to give the user the opportunity to change this on the fly.  However, I have found no way to programmatically get and modify a selector.

Is this something that is not supported?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically modify a selector using [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) .

Here's the code :

```
StateListDrawable state_up = new StateListDrawable();
        state_up.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_up_cyan));
        state_up.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_up_cyan));
        b1.setBackgroundDrawable(state_up);
```

Answer (score 1):

Selectors, Like all Android resources, go through some compile-time processing that optimizes the XML for efficient run-time parsing.  You can't dynamically edit the resources like you propose.

AFAIK the only way to achieve what you want is either manually implement the drawable selection in a custom image selector (not much fun) or limit the users options and have a pre-built collection of selectors that you can switch between at the user's discretion.